# Why does this Joda-Time related test fail sometimes?

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a class, where I calculate the difference in years between current date (`now`) and some other date (`birthday`):

```
import java.util.Date;

import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import org.joda.time.Years;

public class Logic {
    private final Date now;

    public Logic(final Date curDate) {
        now = curDate;
    }

    [...]

    protected int getAgeInYears(final Date now, final Date birthday) {
        final LocalDate nowDate = new LocalDate(now.getTime());
        final LocalDate birthdayDate = new LocalDate(birthday.getTime());
        return Years.yearsBetween(birthdayDate, nowDate).getYears();
    }
}
```

Then I have a unit tests, which validates `getAgeInYears`:

```
public class SomeTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        final LocalDate now = new LocalDate(2015, 8, 28);
        final Logic objectUnderTest =
            new Logic(now.toDate());
        final LocalDate birthDay1 = new LocalDate(2015 - 7, 8, 28);
        Assert.assertEquals(6,
            objectUnderTest.getAgeInYears(now.toDate(), birthDay1.toDate())); // This assertion fails sometimes, but not always
        final LocalDate birthDay2 = new LocalDate(2015 - 7, 8, 27);
        Assert.assertEquals(7,
            objectUnderTest.getAgeInYears(now.toDate(), birthDay2.toDate()));
        final LocalDate birthDay3 = new LocalDate(1981, 4, 24);
        Assert.assertEquals(34,
            objectUnderTest.getAgeInYears(now.toDate(), birthDay3.toDate()));

    }
}
```

The assertion

```
Assert.assertEquals(6, 
    objectUnderTest.getAgeInYears(now.toDate(), birthDay1.toDate()));
```

fails sometimes.

On my machine the test runs without errors. On one of the build servers (Java 6) that test failed. When I rebuilt the code locally using Java 6, the test didn't fail.

What may cause this strange behavior?

**Update 1:** The error message is `expected:<6> but was:<7>`.

**Update 2:** I rewrote the code to get rid of `toDate` calls and got this:

```
public class Logic {
    private final LocalDate now;

    public Logic(final LocalDate curDate) {
        now = curDate;
    }

    [...]

    protected int getAgeInYears(final LocalDate now, final LocalDate birthday) {
        final LocalDate nowDate = new LocalDate(now);
        final LocalDate birthdayDate = new LocalDate(birthday);
        return Years.yearsBetween(birthdayDate, nowDate).getYears();
    }
}

public class LogicTest {
    @Test
    public void getAgeInYearsSunnyDay() {
        final LocalDate now = new LocalDate(2015, 8, 28);
        final AdditionalServicesLogic objectUnderTest =
            new AdditionalServicesLogic(now);
        final LocalDate birthDay1 = new LocalDate(2015 - 7, 8, 28);
        Assert.assertEquals(7,
            objectUnderTest.getAgeInYears(now, birthDay1));
        final LocalDate birthDay2 = new LocalDate(2015 - 7, 8, 27);
        Assert.assertEquals(6,
            objectUnderTest.getAgeInYears(now, birthDay2));
        final LocalDate birthDay3 = new LocalDate(1981, 4, 24);
        Assert.assertEquals(34,
            objectUnderTest.getAgeInYears(now, birthDay3));

    }
}
```

Now I constantly get the assertion error on line

```
Assert.assertEquals(6,
    objectUnderTest.getAgeInYears(now, birthDay2));
```

I expect to get 6, but get 7 instead.

Comment: What are the (EDIT: _actual_) values of those variables?

Comment: @user714965 `now = new LocalDate(2015, 8, 28)`, `birthDay1 = new LocalDate(2015 - 7, 8, 28)`

Comment: That's how you are initializing them. I wanted to encourage you to maybe print the actual values to a test log.

Comment: what is the test error message?

Comment: @sgpalit See update 1.

Comment: @user714965 That's difficult because when the build server doesn't put logging statements of test cases into logs I have access to.

Comment: I am getting the result always 7 :)) it schould be 7 remove 6

Comment: Why do you think that you should get 6 years delta between 2008-08-27 and 2015-08-28??? I think 7 years is right. Months are the same, the delta is even one day bigger than 7 years.

Comment: @MenoHochschild It's not about delta, it's about the **age** of a child born on 28.08.2008. On 28.08.2015, that child turns 7 years old. Before that, e. g. on 27.08.2015, the child is 6 years old. I need the age.

Comment: And I still see that with your data: 2008-08-27/2015-08-27 => 7 years. I would understand 6 years only if you had set your birthday2 to 2008-08-28 (but you have explicitly set it to 2008-08-27!)

Comment: @MenoHochschild Good point. Thanks for spotting that error. If you submit your comment as an answer I'll give you some SO points as a reward (bounty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `java.util.Date` from your `Logic` class and only use the joda classes here. This will make your code much clearer, because there is no need to convert between `LocalDate` and `Date`. Actually doing this makes your test senseless as you would only test `Years.yearsBetween` of joda time which I would expect to be tested already.

I suspect that the bug might be around your `LocalDate`/`Date` conversion, you should check this by printing the actual values of `now.toDate()` and `birthDay1.toDate()` to a test log. And have a look at the javadocs of [LocalDate.toDate](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toDate()):

> Converting to a JDK Date is full of complications as the JDK Date
>   constructor doesn't behave as you might expect around DST transitions.
>   This method works by taking a first guess and then adjusting the JDK
>   date until it has the earliest valid instant. This also handles the
>   situation where the JDK time zone data differs from the Joda-Time time
>   zone data.

Comment: Thanks. Removing `toDate` solved the problem partially, but not fully. See update 2. Let's say I have a child born on 28.08.2008. On 27.08.2015, it is 6 years old. On 28.08.2015 (his or her birthday), the kid becomes 7 years old. The corresponding test fails (see update 2).

Comment: Hm, could it be that `Years.yearsBetween` doesn't reconsider the complete date? Seems as it is only looking at 2015-2008 = **7**

Comment: No, `Years.yearsBetween` correctly looks at month and day-of-month, too. Just test for 2008-08-27/2015-08-28 (=> 7 years), 2008-08-28/2015-08-28 (=> 7 years) and 2008-08-28/2015-08-27 (=> 6 years) I think the OP has just been confused about which day-of-month belongs to which side of comparison.

Comment: @MenoHochschild I corrected that error in Update 2 and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko Your assumption given in your unit-test (update 2) is just wrong. Please look at my previous comment closely which date-times are compared in which way. And I have tested it, too.

Answer (score 1):

**Joda-Time is correct** keeping your code in mind:

You have explicitly set `birthDay2` to 2008-08-27. And your now-variable is the date 2015-08-28. So if you add 7 years to `birthDay2` you will get the date 2015-08-27 which is still one day earlier than 2015-08-28.

The result of 7 years will not change if you have now=2015-08-27 (then the difference is exactly 7 years).

6 years as expectation is only right if you had set `birthDay2` to 2008-08-28 and now=2015-08-27 (because here the day-of-month-comparison prevents the full 7-year-delta).

*Small side note:*

There is one special case around leap days which needs some care (here I think Joda-Time is wrong) - see also this closed [issue](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/issues/132).